# Gating TTL UART Tx pin to simulate BREAK for arbitrary time periods

Tags: digital-logic, uart, ttl

I need to gate a TTL Tx pin @115000bps as the chipset that drives the RxTx lines do not implement UART BREAK for arbitrary time periods.

Thanks to this community's feedback ([Selecting proper vales of Rb, Re and and Rbe in a NPN transistor emitter follower configuration?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51576/selecting-proper-vales-of-rb-re-and-and-rbe-in-a-npn-transistor-emitter-followe)) I have come up with the following configuration that I will connect to the TTL Tx pin of the said chipset, at TTL.TX.In.

[image]

**The Tx output from the whole device will be tapped from TTL.TX.Out**

**BREAK is the gating input** that controls whether TTL.TX.Out will be in BREAK condition or not.

BREAK is an **output pin of a typical FET Microcontroller** - say AVR, MSP430 or PIC.

The TTL levels can be **~5V DC or ~3v3 DC**.

My questions are:

1. What should be the proper value of R1 and D1? (I am thinking R1 = 1K and D1 = 1N4148 but that is very arbitrary)
2. **Is this a proper design** that will allow me to implement BREAK for arbitrary time periods without affecting the "usual" transmission (When BREAK is off and all signals should go through)?

My fears are:

- i. The Vf drop, typically 0.7V can degrade the output signal quality
- ii. The 1N4148 is speced to work upto 4ns but it's capacitance is around 1pF and taking stray capacitance into account, I am not sure how the output signal would look like @115000bps.

Would you have reason to believe that the UART signal outputs could become severly degraded?

I have shared the schematic here. Feel free to make copies and modify it: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/gh3g6z/ttl_uart_gating_public/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuit should work but I would make two serious recommendations.

1) Purge that 1N4148 diode and replace it with a Schottky type, such as a BAT54A, to get a much lower Vf.

2) What is the aversion to using a single logic gate part? Put in a single 2-input gate device to give you the ability to override the UART TTL output to generate the break condition.

If your project is a one-off type or hobby project you should be just fine with approach 1. On the other hand if you are making a commercial product I really recommend approach 2.

Comment: Besides the lower Vf of the BAT54A is there a reason to purge that 1N4148 diode? Will the 1N4148 fail miserably @115000bps?

Comment: @vsmGuy - I do not think that the diode will have a problem switching fast enough for 115.2k baud. Note that the BAT54A (or other similar Schottky diode) will typically switch faster than a normal silicon diode so you have two reasons to toss out the 1N4148.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your microcontroller has fixed-function special purpose pins, you would likely find it much easier to temporarily reconfigure the TX pin as a GPIO, drive it low for the desired period of time, then reconfigure it as the UART output.

Comment: Correct - however, the UART periperal controller in the microcontroller "takes" over the Tx and Rx pins so that the firmware cannot explicitly disable the Tx pin.

Comment: Then you disable the UART and re-enable it.

Comment: True. However, if this can also be done with a DRL why not try that approach? :-)

Comment: Because a software only solution is cleaner and cheaper where it is workable.